# Latest Firebase Admob Interstitial CRASH

Tags: ios, crash, admob, interstitial

I load both banner and interstitial at app startup. It crashed my app upon trying to load interstitial. I installed the admob using pod. Banner works fine.

If I comment out `[self.admobInterstitial loadRequest:request];`, then no crash. If I remove comment, then it crash again. So it is surely due to loading admobinterstitial.

My question is why? The crash doesn't really say much Just `lldb`. I also added the typical frameworks that admob requires -AdSupport, EventUI, etc. But it still crash.

**EDIT**: Seems to be crashing on simulator only. And not in device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution. It is not related to Admob/Firebase at all. It is because I added a Breakpoint Exception as "All". This may cause debugger to crash some messages that is not supposed to crash I guess. Changing the breakpoint from "All" to "All Objective-C Exceptions" solved the issue.